# Update Access database record in C# and refresh it after that

Tags: c#

```
var con = Program.GetConnection();
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
              
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE data  SET [QTY] = '" + textBox6.Text + "' WHERE ID = '" + textBox7.Text + "' ";
      
cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data Updated Successfully");
con.Close();
```

> error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Query '' is corrupt.

can you please tell what is wrong with my code
thanks

Comment: If `ID` is a number you need to take the single quotes off. Consider using OleDbParameters to avoid sql injection and syntax errors.

Comment: You have a problem called Sql Injection that I advise you to look at. But after that it seems that you are passing strings for QTY and ID. Are these fields of type string in your db?

Comment: my id is number but others are string in my access db

Comment: here what I did and its same

Comment: var con = Program.GetConnection();
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE data  SET [QTY] = @value1 WHERE [Part Number] = @value2";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@value1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@value2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

            cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

Comment: Yikes! This looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to solve it with the following

```
var con = Program.GetConnection();
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE data  SET [QTY] = @value1 WHERE ID = @value2";
cmd.Parameters.Add('@value1', OleDbType.Integer).value = textBox6.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add('@value1', OleDbType.Integer).value = textBox7.Text;
cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data Updated Successfully");
con.Close();
```

Comment: There is a stray apostrophe at the end of the query and it should be "@value1" not with a single quote '@value1'. Anyway I think that this will not change anything because you haven't specified the type of the the parameters added. Better use _Add(pname, ptype).Value = value;_

Comment: _cmd.Parameters.Add("@value1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32( textBox6.Text);_

Comment: thanks guys I really appreciate your help Idk why still I have same issue I did all what you said

Comment: here what I did and I have same issue my ID is number but others are string in my access database

Comment: var con = Program.GetConnection();
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE data  SET [QTY] = @value1 WHERE [Part Number] = @value2";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@value1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@value2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

Comment: I edited the answer. Try to assign the connection on the command and let me know how this works.

Comment: OleDb likes `?` placeholders instead of named parameters: `UPDATE data  SET [QTY] = ? WHERE ID = ?`. It's also unclear to me how ADO.Net will respond to an `OleDb.Integer` parameter type with a string Value. I tend to convert those to Integer values before assigning to the parameter.

Comment: @babanjamal Notice this code sets the Connection **before** setting the CommandText. That can be important. Also, it's generally _not good_ with ADO.Net to reuse the same connection object throughout your application. Just reuse the connection string, but create new connection objects for most queries.

Comment: actually I am confused same connection and codes I use it for insert is ok

Comment: var con = Program.GetConnection();
             con.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into [data]([SHELF],[part number],[Description],[QTY],[note],[date])values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "')";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
               
           
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

Comment: @Athanasios Kataras    I do not have anny issue with my connection I tested it it works

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn dear I do not have any issue with my connection my connection is in another class and every time I call it it has not any issue

Comment: I'm talking about assigning the connection to the command: OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;

Comment: all of my data are text except  ID is Auto number others are short text